# What is the sed expression for replacing all occurences of ":{any character}{end of line}" in a file?

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I have a file that looks like the following (simplified) and I'm trying to replace from one string to the end of the line. In this case, I'm trying to replace everything between the very last colon of the line and the end of the line.

**BEFORE**

```
GT:DP:ADALL:AD:GQ:IGT:IPS:PS    0|1:746:196,213:0,0:903:0/1:.:113535
GT:DP:ADALL:AD:GQ:IGT:IPS:PS    0|1:746:196,213:0,0:903:0/1:.:PATMAT
```

**AFTER**

```
GT:DP:ADALL:AD:GQ:IGT:IPS:PS    0|1:746:196,213:0,0:903:0/1:.:1
GT:DP:ADALL:AD:GQ:IGT:IPS:PS    0|1:746:196,213:0,0:903:0/1:.:1
```

Based on a similar question posted, if there were only one colon in the lines, I know the sed expression would be the following, but I'm not sure how to specify the very last colon of the line:

```
sed 's/:.*/1/' file.txt
```

Comment: `.` matches any single character. You have more than one trailing character. Also, there is no `\n` in the target string.

Comment: So instead of `.`, should it be `.*`? And what do you mean there is no `\n`? There are multiple lines in the file, so by default, there should be an `\n`

Comment: "`sed` operates by performing the following cycle on each line of input: first, `sed` reads one line from the input stream, *removes any trailing newline*, and places it in the pattern space." https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
sed 's/:[^:]*$/:1/'
```

`[^:]` matches any non-: character and `$` anchors the match to the end of the line.